# modifying request headers only works on flow but not client

Tags: reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

im new noobie to programing. want to set up reverseproxy for project and wanting to modify request headers for cookie.

when using command in terminal --modify-headers to affect cookie everything work, but using python script everything goes wrong

```
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    flow.request.headers["cookie"] = "mycookie"
```

using this script i can see the cookie is added in flow (terminal) but when looking at network requests from browser the cookie is not there and no changes are made. some help is really appreciate.

thank you all.

Comment: I would stick to the Mitmproxy example script for adding/modifying headers: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#http-add-header

Comment: helo and thanks for the help. i sorted that already but not i see the issue i get is with the thing i trying to do.

i want to get set-cookie from the response and make a new request with that cookie because otherwise server kicks me off. i manage to grab set-cookie and i manage to set cookie but i seem no manage to pass the set-cookie to the cookie because it has to be 2 function (1 request, 1 response)

Comment: I would add print statements to make sure your code is executed at all. Using the example code it may be easier to ensure the code is really used by mitmproxy. Additionally I would recommend to include the used mitmproxy version in your question.